# How to group, sum up and calculate a mean of every other element in a column?

Tags: python, pandas

In my dataframe I have a number of names (string), dates (datetime64), and amount of observations (num).

```
In [8]: df 
Out[8]: 
   name date  num
0     a    1    3
1     a    2    4
2     a    3    9
3     b    1    6
4     b    2    8
5     b    3    3
```

What I want is to calculate for each name an average up-to-date value. So I expect to have the following additional column for each name:

```
   
   name date  num   avg
0     a    1    3     3
1     a    2    4   3.5
2     a    3    9  5.33
3     b    1    6     6
4     b    2    8     7
5     b    3    3  5.67
```

3 = 3/1; 3.5 = (3+4)/2; 5.33 = (3+4+9)/3 and so on for every other name.

I've tried to combine pandas functionalities of groupby + avg and cumsum but cannot get what I want it to be.

There are some requirements: I need to use pandas functionalities (no for loops) and in the best case avoid using lambdas as my df is large.

Comment: Your input and expected output dataframes do not match.  index 5 num changed from 3 to 9.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `groupby` with `expanding` and `mean`:

```
df['avg'] = df.groupby('name')['num'].expanding().mean().reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
```

Output:

```
  name  date  num       avg
0    a     1    3  3.000000
1    a     2    4  3.500000
2    a     3    9  5.333333
3    b     1    6  6.000000
4    b     2    8  7.000000
5    b     3    3  5.666667
```

Comment: In the date column, I have some dates in the future and that is why respective num values are NaN. If we take a name "a" for example I get for the dates 4, 5, 6 three times 5.333333, 5.333333, 5.333333. But I want to have NaN instead. How can I do this?

Comment: @Android44 You add a mask like this `df.groupby('name')['num'].expanding().mean(skipna=True).reset_index(level=0, drop=True).mask(df['num'].isna())`

Answer (score 1):

You can divide [cumulative sum](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumsum.html) by [cumulative count](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) (1 added) for each group:

```
g = df.groupby("name").num
df["avg"] = g.cumsum() / g.cumcount().add(1)
```

where we `add(1)` to cumulative count since it is `0, 1, 2..` but we need `1, 2, 3..`,

to get

```
>>> df

  name  date  num       avg
0    a     1    3  3.000000
1    a     2    4  3.500000
2    a     3    9  5.333333
3    b     1    6  6.000000
4    b     2    8  7.000000
5    b     3    3  5.666667
```

Comment: What does "num" suppose to do? I get an error

Comment: @Android44 That selects the `num` column after groupby (alternative syntax to `["num"]`). You have a column named `num`, right? Can you share the error please?

Comment: You are right, in the original data set I have another column name.